# MPMoviePlayerController resize

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I resize the frame size of MPMoviePlayerController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Since iOS 3.2 you can resize the `MPMoviePlayerController`' view frame.

Set a new frame using `frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);`

## Original answer

You can't

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

> **Behavior in iPhone OS 3.1 and Earlier**
>
> In iPhone OS 3.1 and earlier, this
>   class implemented a full-screen movie
>   player only. After creating the movie
>   player and initializing it with a
>   single movie file, you called the play
>   method to present the movie. (The
>   definition of the play method has
>   since moved out of this class and into
>   the MPMediaPlayback protocol.) The
>   movie player object itself handled the
>   actual presentation of the movie
>   content.

**Update** :

Answer (score 2):

With the new release of the MPMoviePlayerController you can.